# Unexpected token N in JSON at position 2

Tags: php, ionic3

hi can you guys spot where the mistake is? as a beginner ionic dev I am always having a hard time with that sensitive JSON in my PHP file hope you guys takes time to answer this. as a beginner ionic dev I am always having a hard time with that sensitive JSON in my PHP file hope you guys takes time to answer this.

register.ts

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, AlertController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { HomePage } from '../home/home';
import { Http, Headers, RequestOptions }  from "@angular/http";
import { LoadingController } from 'ionic-angular';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-register',
  templateUrl: 'register.html'
})
export class RegisterPage {


@ViewChild("email") email;
@ViewChild("username") username;
@ViewChild("mobile") mobile;
@ViewChild("userpass") userpass;


  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public alertCtrl: AlertController,  private http: Http,  public loading: LoadingController) {

  }

  Register(){
 //// check to confirm the username, email, telephone and userpass fields are filled

  if(this.username.value=="" ){

 let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({

 title:"ATTENTION",
 subTitle:"Username field is empty",
 buttons: ['OK']
 });

 alert.present();
  } else
 if(this.email.value==""){

 let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({

 title:"ATTENTION",
 subTitle:"Email field is empty",
 buttons: ['OK']
 });

 alert.present();

}
 else 
  if(this.mobile.value=="" ){

 let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({

 title:"ATTENTION",
 subTitle:"Mobile number field is empty",
 buttons: ['OK']
 });

 alert.present();
  } else
 if(this.userpass.value==""){

 let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({

 title:"ATTENTION",
 subTitle:"userpass field is empty",
 buttons: ['OK']
 });

 alert.present();

}
 else 
 {


var headers = new Headers();
    headers.append("Accept", 'application/json');
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json' );
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

  let data = {
        username: this.username.value,
        userpass: this.userpass.value,
        mobile: this.mobile.value,
        email: this.email.value      
      };


 let loader = this.loading.create({
    content: 'Processing please wait...',
  });

 loader.present().then(() => {
this.http.post('http://localhost/mobile/register.php',data, options)
.map(res => res.json())
.subscribe(res => {

 loader.dismiss()
if(res=="Registration successfull"){
  let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
    title:"CONGRATS",
    subTitle:(res),
    buttons: ['OK']
    });

    alert.present();
 this.navCtrl.push(HomePage);

}else
{
 let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
 title:"ERROR",
 subTitle:(res),
 buttons: ['OK']
 });

 alert.present();
  } 
});
});
 }

}
}
```

register.php

```
<?php

if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'])) {
        header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: {$_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']}");
        header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
        header('Access-Control-Max-Age: 86400');    // cache for 1 day
    }

    // Access-Control headers are received during OPTIONS requests
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'OPTIONS') {

        if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_METHOD']))
            header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS");         
        if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS']))
            header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers:        {$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS']}");

        exit(0);
    }

  require "dbconnect.php";

    $data = file_get_contents("php://input");
    if (isset($data)) {
        $request = json_decode($data);
        $username = $request->username;
        $userpass = $request->userpass;
        $mobile = $request->mobile;
        $email = $request->email;
    }

$username = stripslashes($username);
$userpass = stripslashes($userpass);
$userpass = sha1($userpass."@la]#}^(dy*%-Ga=/,Ga!.");

$sql = "INSERT INTO users (username,userpass,mobile,email)
        VALUES ('$username','$userpass','$mobile','$email')";

if ($con->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New account created successfully";
} 

else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $con->error;
}

    echo json_encode($data);

?>
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Possibly the `New account created successfully` at the beginning of the JSON?

Comment: oh mmyghad your right why is this happening?

Comment: `if ($con->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New account created successfully";
}`

Comment: ??? and how is this error in jason??? how to fix??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that **everything** that is output from your script ends up in your ajax response. Since you are trying to decode that as `JSON`, you need to ensure that it only contains that. So, rather than echoing a status message, include that in your JSON, with a `success` status or similar. Something like this:

```
if ($con->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    $status = "success";
    $message = "New account created successfully";
} 
else {
    $status = "error";
    $message =  "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $con->error;
}

echo json_encode(array('status' => $status, 'message' => $message, 'data' => $data));
```

Comment: Error [object Object]

Comment: @MjSaijem can you show the code which is producing the error?

Comment: the console didn't show error but there's a pop up "Error [object Object]" when i click register

Comment: That's probably because you're not using the output of `JSON.parse` correctly. If you can add your javascript code to the question I can probably tell you what is wrong.

Comment: I'm not totally familiar with TS but I think you need to change `res=="Registration successfull"` to `res.status == "success"` and `subTitle:(res)` to `subTitle:(res.message)` (in both places that it occurs)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200145/discussion-between-mj-saijem-and-nick).